# Please Check the proof of " show that lub(a,b)=b"

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

$A :=(a,b) =\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a<x<b\}$.

Then lub of $A=b$ and glb of $A = a$.

Clearly $b$ is upper bound for $A$.

Since $\frac{b+a}{2}\in A$.

where $\frac{b+a}{2}$ is midpoint of a and b.
[image]
Let $\alpha$ be an upper bound of A.

such that $a<\frac{a+b}{2}< \alpha$.

If $\alpha \geq b $. If not $\alpha<b\implies \alpha \in (a,b)$.

Now if x is midpoint of $\alpha$ and b then $x=\frac{\alpha+b}{2}$.

$x-\alpha =\frac{b-\alpha}{2}>0 \implies b-\alpha>0 \implies b > \alpha$.

That is $\alpha$ is not an upper bound of A.

And Second Question is How to "show that $\operatorname{glb}(a,b)=a$"
for the seocnd question if we take any $\beta$ such that $a<\beta<\frac{a+b}
{2} < b$

and let $y$ be midpoint of $a$ and $\beta $ then $y=\frac{a+\beta}{2}$.
now $\beta -a =\frac{a+\beta}{2}-a=\frac{\beta-a}{2}>0\implies \beta-a>0\implies \beta\geq a $

Answer (score 1):

I reorganized your proofs below.

Let $x=\mbox{l.u.b.}(a,b)$. Since $b$ is an upper bound, we have that $x\leq b$.
Assume that $x<b$, then we have two cases.

i) If $x\leq a$ then $x<\frac{a+b}{2}\in(a,b)$ and $x$ is not an upper bound. Contradiction!

ii) If $a<x$ then $x<\frac{x+b}{2}\in(a,b)$ and $x$ is not an upper bound. Contradiction!

Therefore $x=b$.

As regards the $\mbox{g.l.b.}$, the proof is similar.

Let $y=\mbox{g.l.b.}(a,b)$. Since $a$ is a lower bound, we have that $y\geq a$. Assume that $y>a$, then we have two cases.

i) If $y\geq b$ then $y>\frac{a+b}{2}\in(a,b)$ and $y$ is not a lower bound. Contradiction!

ii) If $b>y$ then $y>\frac{a+y}{2}\in(a,b)$ and $y$ is not a lower bound. Contradiction!

Therefore $y=a$.